# dseditgroup not returning error but not removing user from group

Tags: macos, mac, command-line, osx-mountain-lion

I am following instructions written by someone else to harden an OS X box. One requirement is to made sure certain system-defined groups have no users in them. For this example I will use _ard, but there are quite a few.

Out of the box, the group _ard has one user in it, also named _ard. So I thought I would use dseditgroup to remove that user from the group:

```
dseditgroup -o edit -u myadminname -p -d _ard -t user _ard
```

I'm prompted for my password, and everything seems to work fine. No error message is returned, but user _ard is still in group _ard.

```
dseditgroup -o checkmember -m _ard _ard
yes _ard is a member of _ard
```

I have tried many permutations, including using `sudo`, specifying `-n .` and spelling out the full paths to the local groups and users.

As a reality check, I put in gibberish names for the group and for the user. In both cases I got back an error message. So the system is recognizing the group and the user, is not returning an error, but is not performing the operation.

Finally I turned to `dscl` to try to accomplish the same thing, also without success. All the permutations I tried based on searches all over the Interwebs, including many permutations of

```
sudo dscl localhost -delete /Local/Default/Groups/thegroupname GroupMembership theusername
```

gave the same result - no error, no result.

So - am I killing myself to follow badly-written instructions and it's not *possible* to remove that user from that group, or am I missing something else?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit to add: Should have mentioned that the GUI will not allow me to remove the users either.

Comment: It may be helpful if you link the instructions you are trying to follow. Also, what version of OS X are you on,and what version are the instructions written for? (there is a surprising amount of change to some of apples proprietary commands between versions)

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't. Internal company documents, need-to-know and whatnot. I can say that it is under the heading "List of groups containing no users:"

Comment: @demure I'm on Mountain Lion, and it's entirely possible the instructions have not been updated for that OS. The instructions don't say *how* to remove the users, just that the groups should be empty, so I've been combing the Web for different methods.

Comment: If `sudo dscl  . -read /Groups/_ard` doesn't contain a line starting with 'GroupMembers: ' (like mine), I would be fairly confident saying that '_ard' is just needed to make the '_ard' group exist.

Comment: @demure - that would also explain why many of the dscl-based solutions I tried returned `<dscl_cmd> DS Error: -14134 (eDSAttributeNotFound)`. I think you're right, and the requirement is just badly written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The _ard group is the primary group for the _ard user.  In the GUI (on 10.6, at least), you might notice that the _ard user is italicized (when looking at the members of the _ard group).

You cannot have a username without a primary group; but, you can change the primary group if you really want to.  Use the GUI to select the _ard user, and set the primary group to something more amenable to you.

Having said that, I'm sure the document creator had the best intentions in mind; but, I don't see how depopulating the _ard group is helpful at all.  (And, ditto for many of the other local _* groups)

Comment: Thanks to both you and @demure. I'm going to march into my audit confident that the real requirement is that no *other* user is in those groups, and I'll fight anyone who says otherwise. I'm giving you the magic checkmark, but hopefully demure can take some pride in a job well done also. Thanks to both of you.